# Angular 7: how to call method from Entry component to parent component?

Tags: angular

Here is my module and i have used DragDropComponent in entry components and my parent component consumed entry component like

parent Component:

```
upload(data) {
    const modalRef = this.model.open(DragNDropComponent, {
        data: data,
        panelClass: 'default-dialog'
    });
invokeMethodToRefreshTables(){

... // code to manipulate some datas after document loaded 
}
```

child:

```
uploadFiles() {
 ...uploaded stuf 
}
```

Module:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    ClickOutsideModule,
    PipesModule,
],
entryComponents: [
    AlertComponent,
    ConfirmBoxComponent,
    DragDropComponent
],
declarations: [
    AlertComponent,
    ConfirmBoxComponent,
    DragDropComponent 
],
exports: []
```

})

all working fine, But i need to invoke  invokeMethodToRefreshTables() once i successfully upload a file, like calling parent component method, How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `afterClosed` observable:

```js
upload(data) {
    const modalRef = this.model.open(DragNDropComponent, {
        data: data,
        panelClass: 'default-dialog'
    });

    // when you close
    modalRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
       // data = modal results - you can pass it from the dialog when you close it
       invokeMethodToRefreshTables();
    });
}
```